# using ethereum in docker, how to allow request from host machine and deny from other machine?

Tags: docker, ethereum

There is ethereum node runing in docker with command: 

`sudo docker run -d --restart=always --name ethereum \
    -p 8545:8545 \
    -p 30303:30303 \
    ethereum/client-go \
    --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --syncmode light --rpcapi eth,personal`

with the option `rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"`, the host machine can access ethereum node, but other machine with external ip also can.

How to deny external machine?

I know it can be done with iptables or some firewall.

Can it be done with docker itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict access to the port 8545 at host level. Just add 127.0.0.1 as the bind address for this port at `docker run`:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always --name ethereum \
    -p 127.0.0.1:8545:8545 \
    -p 30303:30303 \
    ethereum/client-go \
    --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --syncmode light --rpcapi eth,personal
```